# Cron Server with Config in DB (Django)

Tags: python, django

I am searching a replacement for linux cron.

Required Features:

- Django Admin integration: Jobs can be edited via web browser.
- Job scheduling like the usual cron: daily, hourly, weekly and every five minutes, always five minutes after 12 o'clock...
- open source, but no viral license like GPL.

Answer (score 1):

Complex work orchestration with discreet cron instances can blow.

May I recommend Django-cron?  https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron

MIT licensed.